# Removing element from a list by a regexp in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to remove a string that is in parentheses from a list in Python without success.

See following code:

```
full = ['webb', 'ellis', '(sportswear)']
regex = re.compile(r'\b\(.*\)\b')
filtered = [i for i in full if not regex.search(i)]
```

Returns:

```
['webb', 'ellis', '(sportswear)']
```

Could somebody point out my mistake?

Comment: Remove `\b` from the pattern. So, you want to remove all items that *contain* `(...)` in them? Or only those that are fully inside parentheses?

Comment: The ones that are in (). Not the ones that contain ( or ).

Comment: Aha, so you need `match()` with `r'\(.*\)$')`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `\b` word boundary makes it impossible to match `(` at the beginning of a string since there is no word there (i.e. `\b` requires a letter, digit or underscore to be right before `(` in your pattern, and that is not the case).

As you confirm you need to match values that are fully enclosed with `(...)`, you need `regex = re.compile(r'\(.*\)$')` with `re.match`.

Use

```
import re
full = ['webb', 'ellis', '(sportswear)']
regex = re.compile(r'\(.*\)$')
filtered = [i for i in full if not regex.match(i)]
print(filtered)
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/lhXGYB)

The `re.match` will anchor the match at the start of the string, and the `$` will anchor the match at the end of the string.

Note that if your string has newlines in it, use `flags=re.DOTALL` when compiling the regex (so that `.` could also match newline symbols, too).

Comment: Also, since there are `re.match`, `re.search` and `re.fullmatch`, you can use `re.compile(r'^\(.*\)$')`  (with `re.search`) and `re.compile(r'\(.*\)')` (with `re.fullmatch`).

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import re
>>> full = ['webb', 'ellis', '(sportswear)']
>>> x = filter(None, [re.sub(r".*\(.*\).*", r"", i) for i in full])
>>> x
['webb', 'ellis']
```

Answer (score 3):

For my use case, this worked.
Maybe it would be useful for someone finding the same problem

```
doc_list = dir(obj)
regex = re.compile(r'^__\w*__$')
filtered = [ele for ele in doc_list if not regex.match(ele)]
```